# Python named placeholders with nested dictionary (JSON)

Tags: python, json, nested, format, placeholder

Im working with format and named placeholders and trying to figure out:
How is it possible to access nested items (eg. JSON objects) using named placeholders in Python?
For example

```
data = {
    'first': 'John', 'last': 'Doe',
    'kids': {
        'first': 'number1',
        'second': 'number2',
        'third': 'number3'
    }
}  

'{first} {last} {kids}'.format(**data) # Python console
"John Doe {'second': 'number2', 'third': 'number3', 'first': 'number1'}"
```

But how do I write my "named placeholder format", so that I could output

```
 "John Doe, number1, number2, number3"
```

Any clue as how to get the output from a JSON object is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String formatting supports indexing; you don't have to quote keys:

```
'{first} {last}, {kids[first]}, {kids[second]}, {kids[third]}'.format(**data)
```

Demo:

```
>>> '{first} {last}, {kids[first]}, {kids[second]}, {kids[third]}'.format(**data)
'John Doe, number1, number2, number3'
```